# Nicer way to check if string contains all words from an array

Tags: php

Currently I check whether a string contains **all** words from an array like this:

```
function contains($string, array $array) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($array as $value) {
        if (false !== stripos($string,$value)) {
            ++$count;
        };
    }
    return $count == count($array);
}
```

Example call:

```
$string = 'Hello, people at Stackoverflow';
$array = array('Hello', 'People');

if (contains($string, $array)) {
    print 'This is true for the given example';
}
```

I wonder whether a more elegant, faster or even built-in way exists to improve this?

Comment: No need to count. Just reverse condition and return `false` from loop. Whole iteration pass would mean `true`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use something like this:

```
$string = 'Hello, people at Stackoverflow';
$array = array('Hello', 'People');
$i = count(array_intersect($array, explode(" ", preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9' -]/", "", $string))));
echo ($i) ? "found ($i)" : "not found";
```

Outputs:

> found (1)

(`array_intersect` is case sensitive)

Or if you'd like to make it a function, then you could do something like this:

```
function contains($needles, $haystack) {
    return count(array_intersect($needles, explode(" ", preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9' -]/", "", $haystack))));
}

$string = 'Hello, people at Stackoverflow';
$array = array('Hello', 'People');
$i = contains($array, $string);
echo ($i) ? "found ($i)" : "not found";
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you needed to change much. This version terminates when a word isn't found and ensures that the first parameter and every word in the array are strings.

```
function contains_all($str,array $words) {
    if(!is_string($str))
        { return false; }

    foreach($words as $word) {
        if(!is_string($word) || stripos($str,$word)===false)
            { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Breaking words up as others have done:

```
function contains_all_s($str,array $words) {
    if(!is_string($str))
        { return false; }
    return count(
        array_intersect(
        #   lowercase all words
            array_map('strtolower',$words),
        #   split by non-alphanumeric chars (hyphens are safe)
            preg_split('/[^a-z0-9\-]/',strtolower($str))
        )
    ) == count($words);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To prevent needing to perform case-insensitive matching, stabilize your lookup array of "needles" by declaring all words to lowercase. When it is time to process the "haystack" string, convert all of its characters to lowercase with `strtolower()`.
2. To isolate the "words" in the string as an array, you can use `str_word_count()` with a `1` flag to return words instead of word counts.
3. Use `array_intersect()` and specifically nominate the needles array first and the haystack array second.  This will ensure that duplicate matches will only be retained once and in the particular order that the needles are assigned.
4. Finally, check that the original needles array is identical to the newly filtered array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/POtlE))

```
var_export(
    $array === array_intersect($array, str_word_count(strtolower($string), 1))
);
// true
```

The above assumes that you want to match whole "words". If your definition of a "word" differs from how `str_word_count()` defines words, then you may need to pass a third parameter to the function or refactor the algorithm entirely.  I didn't test my approach with multibyte characters, but that would be another valid concern if you may encounter unicode characters.

A regex, multibyte safe approach might look like: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/l7HoC))

```
$result = null;
foreach ($array as $needle) {
    if (!preg_match('/\b' . preg_quote($needle, '/') . '\b/iu', $string)) {
        $result = false;
        break;
    }
    $result = true;
}

var_export($result);
```

This benefits from an early `break` as soon as a needle is not found, but it suffers from traversing from the start of the input string on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `explode(' ',$string)` and then check if the array is a subset of the string-array using [array_diff()](http://php.net/array_diff).